# Android layout issue

Tags: android, xml, layout

I do not want the (black) space between the imageview and the following textview. what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
           <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_contentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club_banner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/condition_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/club_banner"
                android:background="@drawable/overview_cell_header_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/Condition_1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `firStart` uses the `START` constant from the `Matrix.ScaleToFit` that will only chooses to scale the image either x or y axis

[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#START):

```
Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, 
but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one
axis (X or Y) will fit exactly.
```

**solution:**

You need to use the `fitXY` instead to scale the image from x and y axis

Comment: @jay As the documentation is saying. it will fit inside your view but it will at least fit one of the axis, so in your problem it fits your x axis but not your y axis. Why is it doing that?? because it is scaling to maintain its `aspect ratio`

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

This makes the picture fit at the start (top) of the ImageView.

Change the scaleType to something else that matches your needs.

Comment: ok, but it should be possible to use fitstart and have the next element be exactly below the imageview or not?

Comment: Isn't there another one which is possible for you? see http://etcodehome.blogspot.be/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: i could use something else maybe. thing is I didnt write the app myself. is there any other part of the code i could check to see why i have this padding issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I get the expected result.

The problem must be in your image I guess. Is that part below the pic actually transparent?

[image]

Comment: hm no the image has no transparent areas. thanks for checking tho

Answer (score 0):

for whom is interested in this i solved the issue by simply adding

android:adjustViewBounds="true"